# Asp.net Multiview Control resets the dropdown values populated by partial postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, updatepanel, multiview

I have a `Dropdown` on ***View1*** and its populated on `Page_Load`. Underneath that I have 2 `RadioButtons`. When either of that button is selected a **partial postback** happens which repopulates the `Dropdown` depending on my selection. After repopulating the `Dropdown` I move on to next view by clicking a Next button. On ***View2*** I have a `Back Button` when I go back to ***View1*** by pressing that button then `Dropdown` is reset to its original state (means its repopulated with original values which were populated on `Page_Load`).

I have checked my code and didn't find anything which is responsible for resetting the `Dropdown` values. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: have you put your Dropdown binding code under if (!Page.IsPostBack) in page_load event?

Comment: @KevinShah Yes I have put it there.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Javascript to maintain the value of dropdown, such as Session Storage or local storage.   If you are using either of this make sure you set the value of local storage on the place where you do the post back, So when the Postback happens whatever the selected value is will be stored in local storage/ Session Storage and then you can do a "Get" call on setting the default value of that drop down.

Please note: you should not store any sensitive information on this storage as it is visible to user.